# How can I find this limit of $f(n)/n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

First of all, we have arbitrary positive integer $n$ and function $f(n)$. Function is a number of positive dividers of $n$ (for example when $n = 6$, then dividers $- 1, 2, 3, 6$, so $f(n) = 4$. What I need to find is
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(n)/n$. I think it is $0$, but don't know how to prove that.

Comment: Can you find an upper bound for $f(n)$? I think $2\sqrt n$ might work.

Comment: As I can see now in answers your idea was actually right, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find in *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers* by Hardy that, if $n$ is not a prime, $d(n) \approx \log{n}$ for large $n$ with
$$d(n) = \text{card}\{d \in \mathbb N~|~1\le d \le n~\text{ and }~ d | n\}.$$

Comment: Yes, thank you, in this case this limit is 0, as I expected

Comment: Not true. The average value is $\log(n)$ but it can be as small as 2 (for primes).

Comment: I edited the statement.

Answer (score 5):

Given a positive divisor $ d$ of $n$, either $d$ or $n/d$ (or both) is no larger than $\sqrt n$. It follows that $f(n)\le2\sqrt n$.

Now you can squeeze...

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the divisor function, $d(n)$.
Look it up.

In the Wikipedia article on it,
it is stated with a reference that
$d(n) = o(n^c)$
for any $c > 0$.
More precise results are also given.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I've found a lot of useful information in this article